# event listener on svg with d3.mitchTree.boxedTree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've added a click eventlistener on svg generated with d3.mitchTree.boxedTree

The listener trigger only with clicking on text (red zone), not on parent selected element (green zone) as wanted here:

```
selectedNode = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'selected'
    )[0];
selectedNode.addEventListener('click', onClickDescription);
```

I tried to select a  tag instead of the  tag but same problem.

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c8uyzb9/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No bro! The listener is triggering during clicking on areas with the text and parent both. The difference is of the cursor. When you are hovering over the text you are seeing the `pointer` and when you are hovering over the empty area in parent you are seeing the just arrow cursor.
[image]